# How do you put spacing between form elements in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How do you put spacing between form elements in Bootstrap 4? In the code below from the official example, the full name has space from '@' while the username does not have spacing. Does anybody know?

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputName2">Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="inlineFormInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">

  <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroupUsername2">Username</label>
  <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
  <div class="input-group-addon">@</div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroupUsername2" placeholder="Username">
  </div>

  <div class="form-check mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
  <label class="form-check-label">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"> Remember me
  </label>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: what space? the space between the input box?

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe a space between the `@` and `username`, even though it's part of the same input group.

Comment: how about &nbsp;

Answer (score 2):

How about using form-group and form-control div class .

please refer to this one. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use bootstrap's utility spacers themselves.

Comment: Yes, if you're not content of bootstrap utilities then you can add a custom css to satisfy your desired design :)